# Extensive dictionary, including past-tense and plural forms, for a Spell Checker (text file)

Tags: dictionary, text-files

I'm looking for an extensive English dictionary including past-tense and plural forms of words (i.e. "researched" and "notices") in a text file (or .dic). I've tried out a few already, but they're either incomplete or don't include the past/plural forms. Additionally, it would be helpful if it also included the "ing" type of verb - i.e. "running".

This will be used in my application to go along with a spell checker. Can anyone help me find the right dictionary for this situation? This topic can be difficult to search for - everything relates to the .NET Dictionary class...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searched for "text file dictionary" and found a great result here - http://www.winedt.org/Dict/. Includes most words, including plural and past-tense.

Comment: The link is broken and the site doesn't appear to have a separately available English word list any longer.